# Is it possible to apply real time filter to android-camerax?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax

I'm using cameraX for recording video. I need to apply real time filters to the camera preview using [android-gpuimage](https://github.com/cats-oss/android-gpuimage) or any other library. Is it possible? if yes kindly provide an example.

```
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
            val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                .build()

            videoCapture = VideoCaptureConfig.Builder()
                .build()

            try {
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this as LifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview, videoCapture)
                preview.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.createSurfaceProvider())
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("CameraX", "Use case binding failed!", e)
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }
```

I am using camerax version 1.0.0-beta06 in this project

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @iamkdblue No i didn't... actually there is no production release in camerax to use it for video capture or applying any kind of filters on video preview. It seems using camera2 is the only way as of now.

Comment: What about the real-time filter in the image using camerax? How did you implement that efficiently ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both video and filtering are not officially supported by CameraX, but you can work around it by encoding the output of `ImageAnalysis` to video.

The output of `ImageAnalysis` is `YUV420` byte array. It can be converted to `Bitmap` using [this code snippet](https://github.com/owahltinez/camerax-tflite/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/camerax/tflite/YuvToRgbConverter.kt), and then you can apply `GPUImage` filter  against the `Bitmap`. Then encode a series of `Bitmap` to a video. This is inefficient on many levels, but it should work.

You can checkout this code sample for filtering CameraX preview with GPUImage: https://github.com/xizhang/camerax-gpuimage

Comment: That's so helpful, Thank you.

Comment: How can you handle it with video capture? I want to add beauty filter to my videocapture. @arcworks27

Comment: You can use the method above and encode the Bitmap into video. Just be noted this is terribly inefficient.